# Do Paypal recurring payments have unique txn_ids?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using the Paypal "Subscription" button.  I have an IPN handler and overall I think I've got it all figured out.  My last problem is that apparently there's no good way to test a recurring payment (except to wait for the cycle to occur).  This issue is discussed here: [question]: [Testing Paypal subscription IPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364360/testing-paypal-subscription-ipn)

I don't really *need* to test this recurring payment but I do need to know if every recurring payment will have it's own **txn_id** or if every payment in a subscription shares the same ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, each recurring payment cycle will create a new transaction with its own transaction ID.
You'd link these transactions together via their recurring payments profile ID.

Comment: Thank you.  I'd give you a vote up but my rep is still too low!