# How to check subscription of django-paypal while development

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I'm integrating Paypal standard IPN to Django site using django-paypal.
I want to integrate subscribe feature, but have a simple questions while working with it.
Bellow is the dictionary that I'm using.

```
paypal_dict = {"cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
                "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
                "a3": "10.00", # monthly price
                "p3": 1, # duration of each unit (depends on unit)
                "t3": "M", # duration unit ("M for Month")
                "src": "1", # make payments recur
                "sra": "1", # reattempt payment on payment error
                "no_note": "1", # remove extra notes (optional)
                "item_name": "Fogg mobile monthly fee",
                ...
               }
```

I want to check signals like "subscription_signup", "payment_was_successful".
But above dictionary assume that payment occurs once per month.
I want payment occur once per minute or 30 seconds for testing purpose while development, but least time period is 1 day("t3": "D", "p3": 1).

Is there any way I can do it per minute for development purpose?

Looking forward to get help from community. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing Paypal subscription IPN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364360/testing-paypal-subscription-ipn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some extensive research for testing my own application, but the only mention I've found of such a feature said it was removed. So sadly, I don't think this is possible.

I can't find the link right now, if I run into it I will add it to my answer.

**EDIT**: It was actually [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1364465/2615075).